# Message is triggered twice from a command

Tags: python, discord.py

I've read most of the answers on StackOverflow regarding my case since it looks like a common issue!

However, mine is a bit different since my code was working perfectly fine 3-4 days back!

Just to be clear, no two instances of my code are running, neither there is a loop of any sort involved!

Scenario: If the user types in `.ding` on any channel, he should be DM'd `dong!`

I have a `.ping` command in play as well, which I'm using as `on_message()` event. It works fine! I need to get the command to work.

```
@client.command()
async def ding(ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.author
    await channel.send('dong!')
```

This simple snippet sends two messages at once.

Is it because of the recent upgrade?

Comment: Could you share your `on_message`? Are you using cogs?

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for your comment. I got it figured out actually. There were two await client.process_commands(message) in my on_message definition.